# Добавление записи в таблицу

Tags: php, mysql

Создал новую таблицу, где будет список пользователей и их очков.
Делаю запись в таблицу таким образом

```
global $DB;

$DB->Query("update rub_guess_photo set POINTS=POINTS+0.02 where USER_ID='$userid' limit 1;");
```

Вывожу таким способом:

```
global $DB;

$DB->Query("SELECT USER_ID FROM rub_guess_photo ORDER BY POINTS DESC LIMIT 10"); 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {

print_r($row[1]); 
}
```

Но запись почему-то не добавляется и не выводиться. Я вручную создал запись в этой таблице, попробовал вывести - пусто. Где ошибка в первом и втором случае?

Comment: Ну по порядку:
1. Операторы SQL пишутся с большой буквы.
2. Поля БД пишутся в `pole`
3. И уберите точку с запятой в конце первого запроса

Comment: > 1. Операторы SQL пишутся с большой буквы.

Это не требование, а традиция. Можно и маленькими писать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавление записей происходит так:

```
INSERT INTO tabe1 (field1, field1) values ('value1','value2');
```

А UPDATE - это обновление

Вот пример добавления и вывода:

```
<?php
 $connect = mysql_connect('localhost','root','12345');

  mysql_select_db('08ist');
  $name=strip_tags($_POST["name"]);
  $data=strip_tags($_POST["data_rojd"]);

  $sql = "INSERT INTO student (name, data_rojdeniya) values ('$name','$data');";

  mysql_query($sql,$connect);

  $sql="SELECT * FROM student";
  $result=mysql_query($sql,$connect);
     print "<table border=1>\n";
      print "<tr>\n";
     while ($field = mysql_fetch_field($result)) {
        print "<th>$field->name</th>\n";
      }
      print "</tr>\n\n";
     while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        print "<tr>\n";
         foreach ($row as $col=>$val) {
            print "<td>$val</td>\n";
          }
        print "</tr>\n\n";
     }
    print "</table>\n";
?>
```

Проверить есть ли такая запись в таблице или нет, можно таким образом:

```
$sql="SELECT name,data_rojdeniya FROM student WHERE name='$name' AND data_rojdeniya='$data';";
  $result=mysql_query($sql,$connect);
  $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

     if($num_rows>0)
     {
      echo "Такой есть";//в вашем случае обновляем
     }
     else
     {
      //добавляем
      }
```

Comment: Когда тогда проверить есть ли пользователя $userid запись, чтобы знать обновить или создать запись?

Comment: Ну сделайте запрос в базу, и если запрос вернет пустые строки значит нужно добавить, а иначе обновить) Я подправил в ответе)

Comment: Не забудьте принять ответ, или проголосовать) Спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

> 6.4.8 Синтаксис оператора REPLACE
>
> `REPLACE [LOW_PRIORITY | DELAYED]
>         [INTO] tbl_name [(col_name,...)]
>         VALUES (expression,...),(...),...
> или REPLACE [LOW_PRIORITY | DELAYED]
>         [INTO] tbl_name [(col_name,...)]
>         SELECT ...
> или REPLACE [LOW_PRIORITY | DELAYED]
>         [INTO] tbl_name
>         SET col_name=expression, col_name=expression,...`
>
> Оператор REPLACE работает точно так же, как INSERT, за исключением того, что если старая запись в данной таблице имеет то же значение индекса UNIQUE или PRIMARY KEY, что и новая, то старая запись перед занесением новой будет удалена. See section 6.4.3 Синтаксис оператора INSERT.
>
> Другими словами, команда REPLACE не предоставляет доступа к замещаемой записи. В некоторых старых версиях MySQL такой доступ иногда оказывался возможным, но это был дефект, который уже исправлен.
>
> При использовании команды REPLACE функция `mysql_affected_rows`() вернет значение, равное 2, если старая строка была заменена новой. Объясняется это тем, что сначала в таблицу вставляется одна строка, а затем удаляется вторая - дубликат.
>
> Это позволяет легко определять, какое действие произвела команда REPLACE - добавление или замещение строки. Достаточно просто проверить, какое число вернула функция `mysql_affected_rows`() - 1 (строка добавлена) или 2 (замещена).
>
> Следует учитывать, что, если не используются индексы UNIQUE или PRIMARY KEY, то применение команды REPLACE не имеет смысла, так как она работает просто как INSERT.

[Источник](http://mysql.ru/docs/man/REPLACE.html).

Добавит удалит дубликат одним запросом.